# change inet addr:192.168.2.2

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, ip

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 28:e3:47:81:6e:06  
          inet addr:192.168.2.2  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::2ae3:47ff:fe81:6e06/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1088 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1247 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:905412 (905.4 KB)  TX bytes:245531 (245.5 KB)
```

I want to change the `inet addr:192.168.2.2` , because I think it makes internet connection problems, because I don't have internet access, while one the same system (dual boot) my WiFi works fine with Windows. Also when I enter 192.168.2.2 in my browser it redirects me to a project which I did a long time ago and I don't remember what configurations I changed.

Is there way to change my `inet addr` to something else?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** Could you have a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425205#425205) and provide more information so we can give you a better answer?

Answer (score 0):

You should simply stick with DHCP (which is default) and allow your router to assign the IP address to your PC, then you will not have any address issues or conflicts unless you have somehow wrongly configured other devices on the network, for example.

In:

```
/etc/network/interfaces
```

You'll likely see something like:

```
auto eth0
   iface eth0 inet static
   address 192.168.2.2
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   network 192.168.2.0
   broadcast 192.168.2.255
   gateway 192.168.2.1
```

Merely change it back to

```
auto eth0
   iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Of course, if you don't see something like that, or if I misunderstood the question, don't just go around editing files for nothing and ask for clarification ;)

Answer (score 0):

If 192.168.2.2 actually resolves something while running Linux, and Windows works fine with that IP, I suspect you have a VM or docker instance running which claims the IP address. I would figure out what is actually serving from 192.168.2.2 when you make a request, and stop that.

If you need consistent IP addresses, you can you DHCP, but set the router to always assign a certain IP to a particular host.